# tidyr::expand() not adding very small numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data.frame where for each row I want to make N new rows along with a new column. It essentially goes like this. For this 1 row data.frame I want to expand it to 180 rows, differentiated by the new column `probability`. But I found that very small numbers from `pnorm` get dropped.

```
data.frame(col1='a',col2=2, m = 100, s = 3) %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  expand(probability = pnorm(1:180, mean=m, sd=s ,log.p = F)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  nrow()

[1] 125
```

If I switch over to log probability in `pnorm` then all rows are added.

```
data.frame(col1='a',col2=2, m = 100, s = 3) %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  expand(probability = pnorm(1:180, mean=m, sd=s ,log.p = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  nrow()

[1] 180
```

But even with the log transform there are sometimes still some numbers missing so it does not always come out to 180 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expand` is meant to create all unique combination of columns, and since you have only one column `probability` specified, it basically drops all duplicated values in that column, so the result depends how many unique values there are in the generated column; You can double check it by printing how many unique values and compare it with the number of rows in the result:

```
data.frame(col1='a',col2=2, m = 100, s = 3) %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    expand(probability = {
        p <- pnorm(1:180, mean=m, sd=s ,log.p = F)
        print(n_distinct(p))
        p
    }) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    nrow()
# these two numbers are the same
#[1] 125
#[1] 125
```

For your use case, create a list column and then `unnest`ing it should be fine:

```
data.frame(col1='a',col2=2, m = 100, s = 3) %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    mutate(probability = list(pnorm(1:180, mean=m, sd=s ,log.p = F))) %>%
    unnest %>% dim
# [1] 180   5
```